# Creating a mapping of values for an enum

Tags: python, enums, constructor, init, metaclass

So imagine I have

```py
@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    data: str
    metadata: dict
```

I want to construct an enum subclass such that for

```py
class MyObjects(MyEnum):
   OBJ_1 = MyDataClass('some_data', {'some_field': 1})
   OBJ_2 = MyDataClass('some_other_data', {'some_other_field': 2})
```

```py
MyObjects.OBJ_1.value == 'some_data' and MyObjects.OBJ_1.info == {'some_field': 1}
```

What I have so far is a class like

```py
class MyEnum(Enum):
    def __init__(self, my_class_obj):
        self.value = my_class_obj.data
        self.info =  my_class_obj.metadata
```

Very simple, but while `info` is set correctly, trying to set `value` raises an `AttributeError`.

Is there a workaround around that?

It's important for me to put the data in the `value` field specifically, so to not confuse users.

*Actual Context: I'm dynamically creating an enum from the fields of a pydantic model. I want it to provide easy and intuitive access to field name and field information.*